# Android notification Screen

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm creating an ecommerce app and I want to send promotional notifications to users from firebase cloud messaging. I want to show all the notifications in recycler view in notification screen using adapter can anyone tell how do I save all incoming notifications and display them in notification screen

Comment: Which database you are using? Also from where you are sending notification

Comment: Hi Aditya thanks for your reply I'm using firebase database  and firebase cloud messaging

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to show all notifications you need to save those in
   local database when you receive and fetch all on required screen.
   You can use `Room` `database` for the same.
2. You can ask the backend developer to save all notifications at
   backend side and fetch those by an `API`.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

See If you are sending a notification from the firebase console, Then you need to save that notification in the local DB While It receives in Mobile Firebase Messaging Service Class. (but It's not a good approach, Because user loss notification in case of clear data for app or reinstall app)

**Approach 2**

If you are sending notifications using some API or firebase function Then you can create one collection of *Notifications* and save notifications every time while sending And Fetch notifications from the same collection.